# Read variables separated by a character in C

Tags: c, scanf, strtok

I have string like below

`hello:how:23`

Now I need to store these values and assign to variables and I have a code snippet like below,

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char first_wrd[20]= {0}, second_wrd[20] = {0};
    int  num = 0;
    char buf[512+1] = {0};

    snprintf(buf, 512, "%s:%s:%d", "Hello", "how", 23);
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    sscanf(buf, "%s:%s:%d", first_wrd, second_wrd, &num);

    printf("%s, %s, %u\n", first_wrd, second_wrd, num);
}
```

But its not working

```
Hello:how:23
Hello:how:23, , 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `sscanf(buf, "%19[^:]:%19[^:]:%d", ...`

Comment: You're assuming `%s:%s` will stop fulfilling the first `%s` upon encountering the colon. That's not what is happening. `%s` is consuming everything until whitespace, length excess (which you're not providing, so that's out), or end-of-input.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica can you please explain your answer? what is that 19 for ?

Comment: @Hipster1206 He suggested `19` because the target is `20` long and `scanf` needs room for the `\0`.

Comment: why not use strtok? I mean you tagged it strtok

Comment: `char first_wrd[20] ...` so you must use the *field-width* modifier `19` to protect your array bounds. `[^:]` is a character class `[..]` where `^` negates the match of characters in the class. `^:` says all characters NOT a `':'`. So `"%19[^:]"` will read up to `19` characters that are not a colon storing the result at address held by the pointer you provide. Rest should be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

Answer based on chux - Reinstate Monica's suggestion:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    char first_wrd[20]= {0}, second_wrd[20] = {0};
    int  num = 0;
    char buf[512+1] = {0};

    snprintf(buf, 512, "%s:%s:%d", "Hello", "how", 23);
    printf("%s\n", buf);

    if (sscanf(buf, "%19[^:]:%19[^:]:%d", first_wrd, second_wrd, &num) != 3)
    {
        printf("%s\n", "Failed to read the variables!");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%s, %s, %d\n", first_wrd, second_wrd, num);
}
```

The code above in action here: https://godbolt.org/z/b746ocz1P